# Error:The connection to the server was unsuccessfull(fake) in Angularjs App

Tags: angularjs

I am  creating an angular app with Intel XDK.I have data on local storage.when I run the app in offline a message will appear after few minutes like  "Application error:The connection to the server was unsuccessful(fake)" and stop the application spontaneously.how to manage this.I expect a hopeful solution to recover this.

app.js

```
     $scope.checkConnection=function() {
                var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

                if(networkState == Connection.NONE){
                    $scope.footer_message = "No Network Connection";

                    return false;

                }else{
                    $scope.footer_message = "Obidos Technologies (P) Ltd";
                    return true;
                }
            }
 $scope.checkConnection();
```

Comment: I think you should provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . Please show us what you have tried so far to solve this problem and narrow down your question to specific problem.

Comment: please see my above code @KhalidHussain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeing inconsistent/transient error messages saying something like [Connection to server was unsuccessful to “www/assets/index.html”] when starting up your app. This is caused by your App timing out. You can either increase the time-out time, but will only reduce the frequency of the issue, or you can:

1.Rename your index.html to “main.html”

2.Create a new “index.html” and put the following content into it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>tittle</title>
   <script>
     window.location='./main.html';
   </script>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

3.Rebuild your app! No more errors!